# I'm having trouble with displaying a div when I want it to and hiding it when I want it to he hidden

Tags: html, css

line 43 id="eight" is a div that I want to hide when the screen size is below 900px and display when the screen size is above 900px I've used "display: none" line 96 but that seems to hide it when the screen size is bigger than 900px also which is not what I want

here is the [link](https://github.com/BeginnerBen/front-end-web-devolopment-v12) to the GitHub

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the other way around, you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp).
however, here is a brief description

```
@media(min-width:900px) {
```

this is how you are using it and you are supposed to put styles that should be active when the display is over 900px.
Do it like this, change your display under min-width:900px to be something other than display: none, for example:

```
 #eight{
grid-area: newItem2;
display: flex;
}
```

but keep `display: none` out of this and everything should be fine.
the logic is that you set a style that is active when the width of the window is > 900px to display something, and in your CSS before it, you style everything that is under that width. `@media(min-width:900px) {`overrides CSS that is before it, but if you do not override anything it will keep the CSS style you have given it before media query.

Comment: Also, you have `@media(max-width: number) {}` and this would work only belove the width you give it.